# how can i create two child processes, each runs a different program in c

Tags: c, fork, parent-child, pid

i'm trying to create 2 child processes through parent in c, each child process runs a different program?

how can i change this code to let each process run `execution1()` and `execution2()` ?

```
void execution1(char *argve[]);
void execution2(char *argve[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *argve[]) {
  pid_t pid[2];
  int i;

  /* Creation du processus fils */
for(i=0; i < 2; ++i){
  if((pid[i] = fork()) == -1) {
    perror("Erreur lors de la creation du fils ");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if(pid[i] == 0)
    execution1(argve);
   //execution2(argve); how can i let only the 2nd child run this line
}
  /* Attente de la fin de l'execution du fils */
  printf("Attente de la fin du fils...\n");
  if(waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) == -1) {
    perror("Erreur lors de l'attente de la fin du processus ");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  printf("C'est bon !\n");

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you consider using `i` for that? If `i` is 0, then execute `execution1`, if `i` is 1, then execute `execution2`

```
for(i=0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    if((pid[i] = fork()) == -1) {
        perror("Erreur lors de la creation du fils ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(pid[i] == 0)
    {
        if(i == 0)
            execution1(argve);
        else
            execution2(argve);

        // exiting child
        exit(0);
    }

}

// waiting
for(i=0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    if(waitpid(pid[i], NULL, 0) == -1) {
        perror("Erreur lors de l'attente de la fin du processus ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*i'm trying to create 2 child processes through parent in c, each child process runs a different program?*

For this you need to use fork-exec method.

You fork a child then launch new program with `exec()`, the entire memory image of child processes that called `exec()` will be replaced with that of new process created from the program you specified in `exec()`